# Linear independent sets

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-set-theory

Let $S_1\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $S_2\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ be two subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$

Suppose $x_1\in S_1$, $x_1\notin S_1\cap S_2$. $x_2\in S_2$, $x_2\notin S_1\cap S_2$. Show that $x_1$ and $x_2$ are linearly independent.

proof: I am trying to come up with a contradiction by assuming they are dependent and have the fact that either $x_1\in S_1\cap S_2$ or $x_2\in S_1\cap S_2$ but I am not sure how to show this, any suggestions is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x_1$ and $x_2$ are dependent.

So $\alpha x_1+\beta x_2=0$. If $\alpha\ne0$, $x_1=-\frac{\beta}{\alpha}x_2$ and $x_1\in S_2$.

If $\alpha=0$ then $x_2=0$ which contradicts that $x_2\notin S_1\cap S_2$

Comment: You need $\alpha\neq 0$ which might not be the case, but you can assume it wlog.

Comment: If α is not $0$. You didn't say why.

Answer (score 1):

Let it be that $\lambda.x_1+\mu.x_2=0$ and $(\lambda,\mu)\neq(0,0)$ (or equivalently $\lambda\neq0\vee\mu\neq0$).

If e.g. $\lambda\neq0$ then $x_1=\alpha.x_2$ where $\alpha=\frac{\mu}{\lambda}$.

Then $x_1\in S_2$ so that $x_1\in S_1\cap S_2$ and a contradiction is found.

Likewise you can find a contradiction in the other case.